# 0 questions, 0 answers, and a reputation of 371

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

[This user profile on Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6670/shiraz-bhaiji) shows 0 questions, 0 answers, and a reputation of 371.

What has happened is that [What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean/) was migrated from Stack Overflow to Database Administrators, and then the migration was reversed. When it was migrated back, it lost the 4 upvotes that were given while it was on the Database Administrators. The accepted answer points have been deleted from that site.

**Edit**

It now went back up to 386, the 3 badges that related to the question are also still in place.

Comment: How is 371 points, with no questions or answers, expected behavior? The user also has "nice question" and "nice answer" badges, with no questions or answers. If not unusual, it's certainly not what I'd expect.

Comment: Also, expanding the score in [the reputation overview](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6670/shiraz-bhaiji?tab=reputation&sort=post) shows nothing, [except for an association bonus](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uRhiz.png). And most of those dates are way before February 14th, when the user registered...

Comment: Hrm. The 27 upvotes on the answer (that's now deleted as part of reversing the migration) would account for the rep discrepancy (1 + 100 association bonus + 270 from answer votes). Not sure why it didn't get removed when the answer was deleted... I wonder if it has to do with recent changes to preserve rep awarded by posts that are older than 60 days.

Comment: Ah, good call, @AnnaLear! I was thinking it was only around for a few hours/days (I can't see the stub), but I suppose the _original_ post _was_ technically more than 60 days old!

Comment: As @AnnaLear has said, this is due to the recent retention of rep on older deleted posts. Migration mechanics need some changes to help with this, probably a way for a migration to be undone more cleanly.

Comment: [And this guy has 2.8K rep from a reversed migration](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6676/xenph-yan)

Comment: These are holy users. These users are to be venerated, worshipped, paid-homage-to. They achieved what no one else did, invisibility.

Comment: IIRC, badges are always retained, no matter what happens.

Answer (score 2):

As Anna pointed out in her [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125778/0-questions-0-answers-and-a-reputation-of-371#comment339856_125778) the post was from 2009 so is definitely older than 60 days. This means that the user retains the reputation they earn from that post even if it's deleted.

They also retain the badges as they're not removed (and never have been).